# Prove that f=g on the open unit disk centred at 0

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

I have proven that f'(0) and g'(0 ) are non zero and there exists an open subset of E containing 0 such that f,g are conformal if restricted to  it.

Comment: You are a member for almost 4 years and haven't learned mathjax?

Comment: The relevance of the last condition is unclear to me. If $f$ is bijective then $(f')^{-1}\{0 \} = \emptyset$   because $f'$ has no zeros. Also the bijective mappings from the unit disk onto itself are well-known Möbius transformations, and the first two conditions already guarantee that $f=g$ (Schwarz Lemma).